# Excel Constants for Sorting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the sort procedure in Excel VBA and want to have a variable set that changes the order to ascending or descending, depending on a condition.
I tried this but am getting a "type mismatch" error.

```
If SBF = 0 Then
    S = "xlAscending"
Else: S = "xlDescending"
End If  
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SN(x)).sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
        "B3:B" & last_cell), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=S, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
```

Comment: You didn't include the variable declarations in this version. The only issue with it is the use of quotes around xlAscending and xlDescending. Excel would interpret these as string rather than the Enumeration values that the Sort method is expecting. This is presuming that S is a variant or undeclared variable in a module without Option Explicit.

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
Public Enumeration, XlSortOrder, instance

Dim instance As XlSortOrder
If SBF = 0 Then
    instance = xlAscending
Else: instance = xlDescending
End If
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SN(x)).sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B3:B" & last_cell), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=instance, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
```

Comment: The code you have will not work. You've declared Enumeration, XlSortOrder and instance as three variables of type Variant. You've then tried to set instance as type XlSortOrder. This would throw an error.

Either use `Public instance as XlSortOrder` which makes the variable available outside the module, or `Dim instance As XlSortOrder` which makes it local to the module (or sub depending where it is declared)

Answer (score 0):

`xlAscending` and `xlDescending` are Excel Constants. To see what values they have simply print it in Immediate window. See the snapshot below.

[image]

So you can actually write your code as

```
If SBF = 0 Then S = 1 Else S = 2

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SN(x)).Sort.SortFields.Add _
Key:=Range("B3:B" & last_cell), _
SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
Order:=S, _
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Similarly the values of `xlSortOnValues` and `xlSortNormal` is `0`. If you want you can also write the above code as

```
If SBF = 0 Then S = 1 Else S = 2

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(SN(x)).Sort.SortFields.Add _
Key:=Range("B3:B" & last_cell), _
SortOn:=0, _
Order:=S, _
DataOption:=0
```

**EDIT**

I am assuming that `S` has been declared as an Integer or a Long and not as a String.

Comment: You could remove the constants/enumeration values but I think they provide a useful clue as to what the code is trying to do, especially for those who don't code in VBA every day or use particular functions all that often. It also means that in the (very unlikely) event a value changes then it would still work.

Comment: I agree partially with you here. As far as the `clue` goes, one can always comment the code so one know what those values are for. The above demonstration is to show that `xlAscending` and `xlDescending` are constants and not strings :)