# Sort excel column in DESCENDING order

Tags: excel, sorting, powershell

Here is my code that correctly sorts the entire sheet in ascending order based on column 2.

```
$table = $worksheet.ListObjects | where DisplayName -EQ "User_Table"
$table.Sort.SortFields.clear()
$table.Sort.SortFields.add($table.Range.Columns.Item(2))
$table.Sort.apply()
```

I've tried adding xlDescending in various places but keep getting syntax errors back.

Comment: I imagine the syntax errors are because xlDescending isn't defined. You could define it in your script to make your code more readable, rather than using the hard coded values as i suggest below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.sortfields.add.aspx ...

```
SortField Add(
Range Key,
Object SortOn,
Object Order,
Object CustomOrder,
Object DataOption
)
```

Order is the third argument. Combine that with the following answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/11770103/5040941 and you should be able to do something along the lines of

```
$table.Sort.SortFields.add($table.Range.Columns.Item(2),0,2)
```

where 0 and 2 are the values of `XlSortOnValues` and `XlDescending`